# MongoDB Lookup values based on dynamic field name

Tags: mongodb-query

I'm pretty sure the below can be done, I'm struggling to understand how to do it in MongoDB.

My data is structured like this (demo data):

```
db={
  "recipes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "flatbread pizza",
      "ingredients": {
        "1010": 1,
        "1020": 2,
        "1030": 200
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "cheese sandwich",
      "ingredients": {
        "1040": 1,
        "1050": 2
      }
    }
  ],
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "id": 1010,
      "name": "flatbread",
      "unit": "pieces"
    },
    {
      "id": 1020,
      "name": "garlic",
      "unit": "clove"
    },
    {
      "id": 1030,
      "name": "tomato sauce",
      "unit": "ml"
    },
    {
      "id": 1040,
      "name": "bread",
      "unit": "slices"
    },
    {
      "id": 1050,
      "name": "cheese",
      "unit": "slices"
    }
  ]
}
```

The output I'm trying to achieve would look like this:

```
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "flatbread pizza",
      “flatbread”: “1 pieces”,
      “garlic”: “2 cloves”,
      “tomato sauce”: “200 ml”
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "cheese sandwich",
      “bread”: “1 slices”,
      “cheese”: “2 slices”
    }
  ]
```

I've tried several approaches, and I get stuck at the bit where I need to do a lookup based on the ingredient name (which actually is the id). I tried using $objectToArray to turn it into a k-v document, but then I get stuck in how to construct the lookup pipeline.

Comment: This is another example of an unfortunate data model for `recipes` `ingredients` object. If each ingredient was structured like `{"ingredientId: 1010, "quantity": 1}` then `"$lookup"` would be straightforward.

Comment: And again you're absolutely right Rick. These devs man... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a simple solution, and probably can be improved:

```
db.recipes.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      ingredientsParts: {
        "$objectToArray": "$ingredients"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$ingredientsParts"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      ingredientsParts: {
        $push: {
          v: "$ingredientsParts.v",
          id: {
            $toInt: "$ingredientsParts.k"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "ingredients",
      "localField": "ingredientsParts.id",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "ingredients"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$ingredients"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "ingredientsPart": {
        "$filter": {
          input: "$ingredientsParts",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$item.id",
              "$ingredients.id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ingredients: 1,
      ingredientsPart: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$ingredientsPart",
          0
        ]
      },
      name: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      units: {
        k: "$ingredients.name",
        v: {
          "$concat": [
            {
              $toString: "$ingredientsPart.v"
            },
            " ",
            "$ingredients.unit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      units: {
        $push: "$units"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "data": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$units"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "data.id": "$_id",
      "data.name": "$name"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$data"
    }
  }
])
```

You can see it works [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lWmBsTnDf38)

As [rickhg12hs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1409374/rickhg12hs) said, it can be modeled better.

Comment: I see 1 minor issue with this solution. If we change $ingredientsParts in the $project to $ingredientsPart it returns the expected output. Awesome!

Comment: @2dumb `"ingredientsParts"` is arbitrary since it doesn't appear in the output.  The solution already produces the correct output, yes?

Comment: The solution is now updated according to the remark (typo). It produces the output as requested

Comment: @rickhg12hs: it did not (it provided a 1 for each quantity), it does now the typo was corrected

Comment: @2dumb  That's weird.  Using the provided mongoplayground.net example, I get `[
  {
    "bread": "1 slices",
    "cheese": "2 slices",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "cheese sandwich"
  },
  {
    "flatbread": "1 pieces",
    "garlic": "2 clove",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "flatbread pizza",
    "tomato sauce": "200 ml"
  }
]`.